# How to get all order data using sql?

Tags: sales-order, payment-methods, magento1.9.2.3

As magento storing data in multiple tables is quiet difficult to get all the data required using pure SQL. Found some examples but none actually getting details I need about the order.
What I would like to get based on order number is all information about payment and payment status, total amount but no products or quantities using only SQL.
How to do it ?
Or is it possible to use Magento then display whole query in SQL ?

I tried this:

```
    $torders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('from' => $from,'to' => $now))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 'processing')
        ->join(array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id',array('payment_method' =>'payment.method'))
        //->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('from' => $from,'to' => $now))
        ;
```

------ I commented out some lines because if enabled getting 500 error ------

```
    echo $torders->getSelect()->__toString(); <--- this
```

gives me a nice SQL query but how to add all the details about payment method ? how to JOIN payment details into "collection" and filter by selected payment method (ex: paypal) ?

I think I got it, don't know yet why it won't work with array "    $torders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('from' => $from,'to' => $now))
        //->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled'))"

because i need all the orders except cancelled but ... eventually I can use a conditions in a foreach loop later.

Final version (working):

```
$torders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('from' => 
          $from,'to' => $now))
        ->addFieldToFilter('payment.method', array('eq' => 
          'customercredit'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('state', 'processing')
        //->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('nin' => array('canceled'))
        ->join(array('payment' => 'sales/order_payment'), 
        'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id', array('payment_method' 
         =>'payment.method'))
        ->addAttributeToSort('increment_id', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.created_at', array('from' => 
         $from,'to' => $now))
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply this code

```
 $torders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->load();
    foreach ($torders as $order)              
  {
    echo $order;
 }
```

Comment: No no no, what I meant is i would like to add payment details into the query before "foreach loop". I'm doing it now like this, so I can get payment details but not while the collection is created.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't precise so I updated it a bit.